# ColdFusion8 FusionReactor JDBC wrapper - bad driver jars?

Tags: windows-server-2008, jdbc, coldfusion

I'm having trouble getting the JDBC wrapper tool to wrap my ODBC connections.  Before the [version that came out today](http://www.fusion-reactor.com/community/developers/autodev_detailed.cfm?article=FRS-300), it wouldn't even run due to a compatibility issue with CF8.  Now it's saying

> There is a problem with your driver files. Please make sure the driver
>   jars exist and are valid.

Prior to trying this, I used the wrong version of the tool (v0.10) for my build of FR (4.5.0) and had to re-import my data sources into the CFIDE admin and, based on this error, I'm worried I may have neglected some steps in doing so.  The server is also experiencing frequent crashing (which may or may not have anything to do with this problem) and I'm currently reading through the [FR docs](http://docs.intergral.com/display/FR40/JDBC+Driver+Wrapper+User+Guide) but coming up short.  If anybody has any ideas, they would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:  I mentioned using ODBC in this post, but we are actually using the built in CFM connections for MySQL(4/5) and MSSQL (we have 5 separate sources).  Also, here's a picture of the error page:

EDIT2: I'm not allowed to post images apparently v_v  Well you can see it at puu(.)sh/AKkX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since v4.5 of FusionReactor we now require the path to the JDBC driver JAR file when using a driver not bundled with ColdFusion. The reason for this is that some JDBC drivers have a security block on them to ensure they're loaded by a certain class-loader.
To solve the problem you need to enter the path to your MySQL driver JAR file (for a CF9 Enterprise install it's c:\JRun4\lib\mysql-connector-java-commercial-5.0.5-bin.jar on my test system, you'll have to check for the path on CF8 but it will be very similar).
Enter that path in the first empty text box in the right-hand column and tick the "Use for all of this type" checkbox.
Then you should be able to wrap the datasources.

PS/FYI I can't take credit for all of the JDBC wrapper tool - although the first 10 or so iterations were written by myself, since then we've had several people contribute updates.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry that this won't likely be "the answer" you seek, but I would just strongly recommend that you'd be better off asking this question in the FusionReactor Google Group forum/list, where FR engineers and enthusiastic users help each other out. It's a very low-volume list (a few messages per week typically).

I just fear that your problem is too you specific (related to this brand new release of the free wrapper tool) to expect many SF readers to be able to help. BTW, while the tool is not formally supported, it is written by one of the FR engineers (and offered as a community resource) and he would certainly respond if you asked your question there.

http://groups.google.com/group/fusionreactor

Comment: No sooner had I posted this, but I saw that you had posed the question on the group but it was awaiting moderation. As I'm one of the moderators, I just let it in. Let's hope you get the answer there. :-) If you do, I hope you may come back here and offer it.

I do see that you offered a link in that email to this. Great. For readers here, I'll offer the link now to that discussion:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/fusionreactor/TZl04_UH_js

(I'm not sure, with the new format of GG, if that's a good URL to "share". We'll see.)